# Tree level and loop level

Tags: string-theory, symmetry, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein, branes

I'm trying to read through a paper which explains the following about Universal Extra Dimensions (UED) vs [ADD models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimension):

> The new feature of the UED scenario compared to the brane world is
>   that since there is no brane to violate translation invariance along
>   the extra dimensions, momentum is conserved at tree level leading to
>   degenerate KK mode masses at each level and conservation of KK number
>   in the interactions of the four dimensional effective theory. This
>   statement is broken at the loop level, where the fact that the extra
>   dimensions are compact leads to (calculable) violations of the full
>   Lorentz symmetry, and as a result shifts the masses of the KK
>   modes away from their tree level values.

I'm unfamiliar with the concepts of tree-level and loop-level. Could someone perhaps explain this in context? If I would have to guess, I'm thinking that tree-level correspond to the scattering correlation functions of the classical theory and loop-level are a kind of correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer-as-diagram:

[image]
([source](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v7/107))

From an answer-as-comment:

> "I'm thinking that tree-level correspond to the scattering correlation functions of the classical theory and loop-level are a kind of correction?" Indeed you are right. The terminology comes from quantum field theory and refers to Feynman diagrams. Tree-like Feynman diagrams give the leading order terms in perturbation theory and the loop diagrams come in with a factor of ℏ for each loop. This is developed in any book or decent set of lecture notes on QFT. :)